# Access server folder

Tags: magento-2.1

I need to access server folder of project.

ie. `mydomain.net/my_project` through my system's command prompt in order to run magento commands. For example `php bin/magento setup:upgrade`.

I'm using `windows 10 Operating System`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For windows, you can use putty software to connect to SSH in your web server. After connecting with putty, you can navigate to your folder and run commands for Magento 2.

Answer (score 0):

As @krishna said you can use putty to connect your server via ssh

this is the tutorial how to use putty

https://mediatemple.net/community/products/dv/204404604/using-ssh-in-putty-

and then go to your root directory via `cd` command

```
cd  mydomain.net/my_project
```

and use command in that directory like

```
bin/magento setup:upgrade
```

If its a Linux server then you don't need php before `bin/magento`

Comment: I tried using putty.Added ip address in putty configuration but showing blank cmd prompt.

Answer (score 0):

I found the way to connect using putty.If we are using windows we need to install putty.exe,pagent.exe,puttygen.exe.Then we need to generate ppk file using puttygen and add that key into pagent also.Then run the putty software.